# One hour interval - Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I'm trying to select all records based on date/time.
I have this timestamps in postgreSQL:

```
13/12/2020 11:00:00
14/12/2020 11:31:00
14/12/2020 12:30:00
14/12/2020 13:00:00
15/12/2020 02:00:00
```

I have a code in the controller getting all records:

```
    $start_date = date('d/m/Y 00:00:00');
    $end_date = date('d/m/Y 23:59:59');

    if($request->start_date != '' && $request->end_date != '')
    {
        // if user fill dates
        $dateScope = array($request->start_date, $request->end_date);
    } else {
        // default load page - today
        $dateScope = array($start_date, $end_date);
    };

  $results  = Tablemodel1::whereBetween('table1.recordtime', $dateScope)
    ->selectRaw('table1.recordtime','table2.info')
    ->orderBy('recordtime', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

The goal is to select only records in every hour like this:

```
13/12/2020 11:00:00
14/12/2020 13:00:00
15/12/2020 02:00:00
```

I get error when use:

```
  $results  = Tablemodel1::whereBetween('table1.recordtime', $dateScope)
    ->selectRaw('extract(hour from table1.recordtime)','table2.info')
    ->orderBy('recordtime', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

The error is:

```
Undefined index: recordtime
```

Comment: so what's wrong with your code ? any errors ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `LIKE` to get the records with timestamps that have no minutes or seconds and if there's no other processing required.

```
$results  = Tablemodel1::whereBetween('table1.recordtime', $dateScope)
    ->where('table1.recordtime','LIKE', '%:00:00%')
    ->selectRaw('table1.recordtime','table2.info')
    ->orderBy('recordtime', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Also, your query could probably work with this slight fix (`AS column_name`)

```
$results  = Tablemodel1::whereBetween('table1.recordtime', $dateScope)
    ->selectRaw('extract(hour from table1.recordtime) AS recordtime','table2.info')
    ->orderBy('recordtime', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, the first method is very smart :) But with the fix still wont work. Anyway problem solved! :)

Comment: :) yeah just a shortcut to save all the processing and complications with time formats, still if the second query works, try to find out which is faster (like or extract), second query might work if you use `Group By`

Answer (score 2):

Please try something like this:

```
$result = Tablemodel1::select([
                 DB::raw('count(table2.info) as counted_info'),
                 DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(table1.recordtime, "%H") hour'),
          ])
          ->whereBetween('table1.recordtime', $dateScope)
          ->groupBy('hour')
          ->orderBy('hour')
          ->get();
```

You should do the next steps:

1. Format date
2. Group by formatted date (Example: `DATE_FORMAT(orders.created_at, "%b %d") day`)
3. Sort (optional)
4. collect data

All possible formates described here:
[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your spended time to write this. I did try your method but its not working(I have more complicated code and cant integrate it) and its a bit long way compare to the other answer

Comment: No problems. Great, if you already solved your issue